# Count amount of entries in an array from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: typescript

I have a realtime database on Firebase and I'd like to count the amount of entries in my JSON object. This will be used to add as a parameter to Adding another entry to a new entry as I have an 'id' field. I would retrieve the count and increment for the new entry.

I can subscribe to to the database and retrieve back my JSON object and output it to the console window, but I really just need to count the entries and don't know what the best/recommended way of doing this is or if indeed is the preferred method.

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(_jsonURL)
}
this.getJSON().subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data)
})
```

So from getting that JSON data I thought I could count the entries from that call. But a bit stuck on where to go next.

Comment: what does the JSON `data` looks like after `subscribe`? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes it returns in an array through the console window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just the *count* of the items, you can just [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) your response from an array to its length.

To do that use the `pipe` operator first, the put your `map` inside of it. The whole thing will look like this

```
public getJSON(): Observable<number>{
    return this.http.get(_jsonURL).pipe(
        map(x => x.length)
    );
}
```

## Edit

To use this in you code, you can use the *result* that comes from `getJSON()` and increment a certain variable (`totalCount` in my example) to keep a total count

```
let totalCount = 0;

this.getJSON().subscribe(count => {
    console.log(`returned count = ${count}`);

    totalCount += count;
});
```

Comment: thanks, how do you store this as a variable so I can use the result later on in my code?

Comment: Thanks, but the totalCount never adds to the let totalCount. This is what I was initially trying and it was driving me crazy..

Comment: include a `console.log(totalCount)` inside the `subscribe` after `totalCount += count`. Tell me what do you see?

Comment: Okay so if one cannot output the value from a promise or subscribe but only to console.log, how does one write a new entry to the JSON object indicating the new id number? Can you auto-increment like in SQL?

Comment: __you can subscribe__, look at my answer. And what you just asked is a totally different question. If I answered your first question then mark this as answered and post a new question